# How to write/read the online file's data to/from Python without downloading the file?

Tags: python, python-3.5

I am trying to write a program in Python 3.5 that will be the main interaction between Teachers and Students. The teachers will be able to Upload test marks and attendance from their PCs and students will be able to check out their scores and whole report on their home i.e. it is a Student Portal type app.

The whole code is written and is working. Now the final and most difficult part is that I have to take the data online.

I want my Python app to:

1. Automatically update the online file if the teacher makes some update to it.
2. Show the students their report without downloading the file.

I do have a Dropbox account and I want to keep the data file there.

Comment: Please show the code that you have already tried.

Comment: Is this a hosted web application that people access via URL? If so, you might want to look at creating a simple database that will house this data that users can interact with. Students will get a view of their grades that you craft by querying the database for that particular student. Teachers will make whatever changes necessary and your code is responsible for knowing how to update the database based on the teacher's request.

Comment: No Sir It is not a web hosted application. In Final Form, it will be an .exe program.

Comment: Sir @MarkyPython I want to keep this code Private. If I can contact you through personal message, I can surely share this code with you.

Comment: If you want to keep the code private then you have come to the wrong place.  Stack Overflow is a community of developers who help you find and fix issues with code that you write.  Our job is to help you with your code, not write it for you.

Comment: Muhammad: @Marky is quite right. Furthermore it is worth noting that beginners frequently over-value their code, believing it to be extremely valuable and worth stealing. In reality, most code is not worth stealing, since it is cheaper to write from scratch than try to use someone else's material. I would therefore recommend editing your post, since it is likely to close in its present condition.

Comment: @halfer You are absolutely right.  Code is so much less valuable than some people believe.

Answer (score 2):

Like it was mentioned in the comments, you have to know this is a community where users share their code with a potential problem, and all of the users tend to try to help them. Also the code remains here so if other users relate to this issue they can be helped by an already existing answer. Having said that, what can you do For the Student section, is to fetch all the "uploaded files" including student's mark parse it, get specific student's marks based on some criteria, and display them to Student without displaying the whole file. As for the Teacher, you could just use a library for DropBox so you can upload files.

This is not the optimal solution. A more optimal solution is to use a database, so the teachers can upload marks to a database, or if they upload files, to be a service that parse this file and add the marks to the database. And a Service so it can retrieve Student's marks based on Student's credentials. This would be a more optimal solution.

Beside that we can't really do anything to help you without providing a form of source code, and an issue that can be resolved. Have in mind Stack Overflow is not a place where others write code for you. It's a place where people try to help you resolve issues with your current code, or logic.

Comment: Great answer and good job explaining how it should work without actually writing the code for him!